# questions related to DTD and schema: finding the missing words

Tags: xml, schema, dtd

This question are part of a quiz. I've finished already but some questions were answered incorrectly. 
However, the teacher don't upload the solution for those questions.
Would you please help me for the solution of such questions? I need to know exactly the answer in order to start revise for the final exam

This question related to DTD and schema:

1) Identify the missing word. _____ is used as a pointer to a notation that makes an association between a name and a special type of content.

Selected Answer (Incorrect): ADATA

2) An example of syntax for an _____ declaration would be <ATTLIST MEMO (CON|PUB) "PUB" >

Selected Answer (Incorrect): attribute type

3) Identify the missing word. (1)_____ entities are also known as (2)_____ entities.

Selected Answer (Incorrect): (1)parsed, (2)text

4) Which of the following is an advantage of XML Schema over DTDs?

Selected Answer (Incorrect): It is often simpler to express constraints using XML Schema.

Answer (score 1):

Was this multiple choice? What were the other choices?

For 1 and 2 I can guess:

1) NDATA (NDataDecl)

2) attribute-list

(What kind of exam needs you to know horrible old cruft like Notations, huh? Yuck!)